# Como concatenar um input name com uma variável em jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Eu possuo uma tabela que contêm um botão que adiciona uma linha na tabela cada vez que clico nele. 
A linha criada possui 4 inputs, um destes inputs possui uma função auto-suggest / auto-complete que busca informações no banco de dados e retorna estas informações para os outros 3 campos de inputs. Conforme a imagem abaixo

[image: Tabela criada]

Código:

```
<script>
 $(function(){
 var cnt = 0;
 var quantidadedisponivel;     

 $("#adicionar_item").click(function(){

    $('#tabela_publicacoes tr').last().after('<tr><td>#'+cnt+'</td><td><input type="hidden" name="titulopublicacao'+cnt+'" id="titulopublicacao'+cnt+'" style="width: 600px;"></td><td><input class="form-control" name="cod_publicacao'+cnt+'" type="text" disabled="disabled"></td><td><input class="form-control" disabled="disabled" name="valorunitario'+cnt+'" type="text" value=""></td><td><input class="form-control" name="quantidadedisponivel'+cnt+'" id="quantidadedisponivel'+cnt+'" type="text" disabled="disabled" value=""></td></tr>');        

     $('#titulopublicacao'+cnt).select2({
        placeholder: "Digite o título da Publicacao",
        ajax: {         
            url: 'autosuggest_busca_publicacao.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 50,
            data: function (term) {
                return {
                    term: term
                };
            },
            results: function (data) {
                var results = [];                   
                $.each(data, function(index, item){
                    results.push({                          
                        text: item.titulopublicacao + " - Número: " + item.numero + " - Ano: " + item.ano,
                        id: item.cod_publicacao,
                        quantidadedisponivel: item.quantidadedisponivel                         
                    });                     
                });
                return {results: results};
            }
        },
    }); 

$('#titulopublicacao'+cnt).change(function() {  
        var selections = ( JSON.stringify($('#titulopublicacao'+cnt).select2('data')) );
        //console.log('Selected IDs: ' + ids);
        console.log('Selected options: ' + selections);
        //$('#selectedIDs').text(ids);          
       $("input[name='quantidadedisponivel"+cnt+"']").val(selections);
    });

cnt++;

$("#anc_rem").click(function(){
    if($('#tabela_publicacoes tr').size()>1){
        $('#tabela_publicacoes tr:last-child').remove();
    }else{
        alert('Erro, não foi possível remover');
    }
 });            
});
</script>
```

Parte HTML:

```
<table id="tabela_publicacoes" class="table table-hover">
<thead>
   <tr> 
         <th>Item</th>
         <th>Título</th>
         <th>Código</th>
         <th>Valor Unitário</th>
         <th>Quantidade Disponível</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="adicionar_item"><button class="btn btn-md btn-success btn-next">Adicionar Item</button></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="anc_rem"><button class="btn btn-md btn-danger btn-next">Remover Item</button></a>
```

Meu problema é que não consigo retornar os valores para os 3 inputs.
A declaração `$("input[name='quantidadedisponivel"+cnt+"']")` com o `+cnt+` concatenado dá problema, estou declarando de forma errada?

Comment: Sugiro mudar a estratégia de código. Usando cada `tr` e ir buscando o `.parent()` a cada `.change()`. Se colocar também o HTML da parte que tem na imagem posso responder com uma sugestão

Comment: Obrigado Sérgio, segue a parte html editada

Comment: Qual erro que o console produz? E, faça um `console.log(cnt);` antes de `$('#titulopublicacao'+cnt)` e me diga o retorno.

Comment: Guilherme, grato pela ajuda.

O retorno do log:

Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui fica uma ideia:

Retire toda esta função 
`$('#titulopublicacao'+cnt).change(function() {`

Em vez dela crie uma função à parte assim:

```
function change(el) {
    var data = $(el.target).select2('data');
    var quantidade = data.quantidadedisponivel;
    var input = $(el.target).closest('tr').find('input').last().val(quantidade);
}
```

Esta função pode agora ser chamada quando o seu select receber uma mudança de valor. Repare que mudei um pouco o que tinha. Não compreendo porque tinha o stringify...

Para isso ter de adicionar um event handler ao select assim:

```
$("#adicionar_item").click(function () {
    // etc

    $('#titulopublicacao' + cnt).select2({ // aqui começa o select2...
        placeholder: "Digite o título da Publicacao",
        // ect...

    }).on("change", change); // aqui no final junte isto
```

Esse evento tem o elemento mudado lá dentro e pode usar isso. Não copie a parte de ajax do exemplo em baixo, mudei para poder fazer o exemplo.

**Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/JkV5q/**

Comment: Obrigado Sérgio, vou testar aqui !!!

Valeu mesmo =)!